# Add items to list and then print it (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm currently working on a restaurant app on iOS and I'm kinda new to programming.

Now, in my app, I have items in a `tableView`, and I want the user to add the items to a list (Their Order) and they must be able to view that list with their items in it.

If they are satisfied, they must be able to print it to a printer connected on a network and if they print it, it must look more or less like this:

1. *item* (with their price on the end)
2. *item*
3. *item*

Total (and then the total amount of all the items on the list)

If this is possible, can you please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Anything can get print the question is what do you want to print, View or you want to create a new memo

Comment: First you must be familiar with what is UIViewController and how its life cycle is being handled? Followed by tableview's delegate and datasource implementation. And then AirPrint iOS API. And you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, your app creates a print job, providing either an array of ready-to-print images and PDF documents, a single image or PDF document, an instance of any of the built-in print formatter classes, or a custom page renderer.

In iOS 4.2 and later, apps can add support for printing content to local AirPrint-capable printers. Although not all apps need printing support, it is often a useful feature if your app is used for creating content (such as a word processor or a drawing program), making purchases (printing order confirmations), and other tasks where the user might reasonably want a permanent record.

This chapter explains how to add printing support to your app. Just go through the developer.apple - [Drawing Printing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html)